# How do I set max browsing history size?

Tags: firefox, history

How do I set how many URLs (maximum) can be stored in the browsing history of Firefox?

I don't see such an option in the settings dialog.

Answer (score 21):

**NOTE: I'm using Firefox 40.0.3 here.**

I believe the relevant option is **`places.history.expiration.max_pages`**. It doesn't exist by default, so you'll have to go to **about:config** and create it.

Once you create it and set it, check the value of `places.history.expiration.transient_current_max_pages` — it should automatically adjust itself to match your `.max_pages` setting. If this is the case, it means you've set `.max_pages` correctly.

### Results:

(Now on Firefox 52.0.2)

It's 2017 and since I wrote this answer I don't seem to have lost any history. My oldest history entries (from 2013) are still there. I have well over 100,000 pages in history and my "places.sqlite" is 71 MB.

### Technical details:

The relevant function is `PEX__loadPrefs()` in [nsPlacesExpiration.js](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/places/nsPlacesExpiration.js). It tries to determine the limit by first checking `PREF_MAX_URIS` (which is `"max_pages"`). If `PREF_MAX_URIS` isn't set or is a negative value, it then attempts to calculate the 'optimal database size' based on available memory and disc space. So, it appears that setting `places.history.expiration.max_pages` overrides all this logic.

If you want it to retain all history ('infinite' history) you could try setting `max_pages` to 2147483647 (the highest 32-bit signed integer). I haven't actually tested this myself, but the database would probably be crushed under its own weight before reaching this limit.

Comment: came from https://superuser.com/a/995462/

Comment: it's in *v4*, at least v4.0b11, see my comment https://superuser.com/questions/647546/how-to-set-up-firefox-to-absolutely-never-to-delete-any-history-items/995462#comment1375132_995462

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  For someone who's new in firefox-dabbling, how can I create a new option in about:config?

Comment: Got it (thanks again google) - right-click in the window and choose Integer.

Comment: doesn't seem to be taking effect on Android. haven't worked out why yet

Comment: "… try setting _max_pages_ to 2147483647 … " https://superuser.com/questions/1269516/what-exactly-does-the-number-listed-under-places-history-expiration-transient-c#comment2013063_1307644 I wonder about automated changes to transient`places.history.expiration.transient_current_max_pages`

Comment: i recently took another look at the code; things seem to have changed a lot since i wrote this answer.
i'm planning to see if i can find an updated solution (which works on android hopefully)

Comment: @Cauterite, is [this](https://superuser.com/a/1341908/285720) a viable solution?

Comment: Also I think it's worth to recommend setting `places.history.expiration.interval_seconds` to a large number so that it doesn't even try to expire every 180 seconds (by default). For better performance.

Comment: @user (re: question 1341762): i guess that could work, but seems like overkill — the value of `places.history.expiration.transient_current_max_pages` has still never changed  in my browser since i set the `places.history.expiration.max_pages` option in 2015

Comment: @Cauterite: That's good then, after your previous comment I was under the impression that it no longer works. Could you also confirm that you have history entries from 2015?

Comment: @user You bet — i have all my history since *2014*. The changes i was worried about seem to add some new behaviour it detects low disk-space, so for now i recommend always keeping your FF profile on a volume with ample space.