# Does Firefox ship with a new default for "history expires after..."?

Tags: firefox, history

[image: Firefox settings for 'History']

So I use the above <kbd>Preferences → Privacy</kbd> settings since forever, but only recently (since FF 46 or so) my "sites I have visited" seem to vanish from my browsing history earlier than they used to!?

Can somebody confirm this? And as there is (see screenshot again) no UI to control for how long FF should "Remember my browsing and download history", what's the proper `about:config` value to set it? (Right now it seems to be 14 days.)

My `places.history.expiration.transient_current_max_pages` is set to 72070 - a max page count?? - Isn't there a value to set it based on how long ago the visit was?

Comment: Hmm. I haven't changed any settings. I have history going back to March ...

Comment: I did not mention one thing: I had system disk fill up a few times back then, and it could be that FF automagically adjusted history settings (to "less history") when that happened - is that possible?

Comment: See also: [How do I set max browsing history size?](http://superuser.com/q/895302/151741)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How do I set how many months of history Firefox remembers?

`places.history.expiration.max_pages` is maximum number of pages that are retained before pages are expired.

> I had system disk fill up a few times back then, and it could be that FF automagically adjusted history settings (to "less history") when that happened - is that possible?

Maybe.

> The new component is able to detect your hardware specs, especially
>   memory size, and adapt expiration to it.

**Workaround**

Consider using the extension [Expire history by days](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/expire-history-by-days/).

Ironically this extension was written by the [developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/expire-history-by-days/developers) who changed the previous behaviour. See the blog post below.

---

#### How do I set how many months of history Firefox remembers?

> Current Firefox versions keep a maximum number of visited page and do not have a time limit for the history. Firefox determines automatically how many pages can be kept without affecting the performance.
>
> You can see the current value of this maximum as the value of the read-only pref `places.history.expiration.transient_current_max_pages` on the `about:config` page.
>
> See Marco Bonardo's blog about this subject:
>
> http://blog.bonardo.net/2010/01/20/places-got-async-expiration

Source  [How do I set how many months of history Firefox remembers?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1059856)

---

#### Places got Async Expiration

The blog link is no longer available, but from the wayback machine:

> **A better expiration component is now part of Places module**
>
> Last week, on Friday, I've pushed the last pieces of the new Places Expiration component. This was one of the Firefox Projects intended for 1.9.3 branch, you can find more background on the start of this project in its wiki page.
>
> Some background:
>
> Originally expiration was managed by History component itself on three
>   major steps: after each visit, during idle, at shutdown. This had
>   various drawbacks. First of all it was making navigation experience
>   laggish, so we moved the after each visit step to be after each sync
>   between memory and disk tables. We also reduced idle expiration and
>   shutdown expiration.
>
> The result was better, but we had other issues: we were not expiring
>   enough pages related to the number of visits, and the sync component
>   was now bloated with non-related functionality (And slower). We were
>   also still doing a bunch of stuff at shutdown.
>
> In bug 516940 i cleaned up the shutdown stuff, while increasing
>   separation between History and Expiration, at that point was easier to
>   split it out of History in a separate component. So, what's new?
>
> The new component is a JS component, it runs expiration in steps,
>   every 3 minutes, with a simple adaptive algorithm, so that if the last
>   step did not expire enough, the next one will be run later, while if
>   it finds more items than the expired ones, the next step will expire
>   more! This should ensure we don't lag behind with expiration.
>
> It also uses async Storage API, this ensures that we run I/O in a
>   separate thread, so we won't hurt your navigation.
>
> Expiration on idle will run just a single larger step, then it'll stop
>   till you exit idle, this way it won't kill your standby or batteries.
>   Expiration on shutdown runs a larger step, but not too large, in most
>   cases the adapative expiration steps should still ensure we don't
>   expire on shutdown. What has changed for you?
>
> The new component is able to detect your hardware specs, especially
>   memory size, and adapt expiration to it, this means you don't need
>   anymore to tweak number of days of history, or whatever. For this
>   reason we have removed the number of days field from the preferences
>   panel, you don't need anymore to tell us how much days of history your
>   computer can handle.
>
> What about privacy? Well, we discussed about that obviously and we
>   went to a conclusion that the days field was not giving back any real
>   privacy gain. Sure i could have set it to 6 days, but that would have
>   not protected me since:
>
> - The days pref was an "at least" pref, so for most users it was really a fake-change
> - Being expiration async per definition, you can't be sure when pages are physically expired
> - even if you reduce history to 6 days, nobody can ensure you don't have bad entries in these days
>
> Since we have better privacy tools (And we can even build new ones, so
>   feel free to suggest changes and file enh bugs about that) like Clear
>   Recent History, Private Browsing and Forget about this page/site, the
>   choice was pretty clear, we want real privacy, not fake-privacy.
>
> Also hidden expiration preferences have gone, so
>   browser.history_expire_days, browser.history_expire_days_min,
>   browser.history_expire_sites are now replaced by a single
>   places.history.enabled preference. No more need to read preferences
>   manuals just to make the browser feel faster.
>
> What can you tweak? Ideally you don't need to tweak anything, and i
>   suggest you don't touch any pref. Btw, for the sake of information we
>   have two new hidden preferences:
>   places.history.expiration.interval_seconds is number of seconds
>   between each expiration step, while
>   places.history.expiration.max_pages is maximum number of pages that we
>   will retain before expiring. We make our best to have satisfying
>   default values for anyone, current values are built to be pessimistic,
>   we will evaluate how we behave with them, and eventually increase them
>   in future, if we feel that's needed.

Source https://web.archive.org/web/20151229082536/http://blog.bonardo.net/2010/01/20/places-got-async-expiration

Comment: Thanks David for digging this up. But regarding what FF does now, my 2 cents are: "arg!" (wanting to shake Marco for this poor decision) .. So FF is now being smart for me? NO!! I use History as "outsourced memory" of sorts, and he/they came up with a "better" solution that simply discards it, without asking, based on how much RAM I have?? So wrong. The better implementation would've been to keep in memory "the tip", the amount the host machine can handle "without affecting performance", and offloading everything else to disk - so it's accessible through the "Library"/Show all History pop-up!

Comment: With this (History) not being adjustable anymore, FF just became 20% less useful for me.

Comment: @isync "I use History as "outsourced memory" of sorts" I would suggest that is what bookmarks are for ...

Comment: @isync You might want to check out  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/expire-history-by-days/. written by guess who?

Comment: Bookmarks are for "I know now I'll need this URL in the future", History is for "arg! I wish I'd bookmarked this, eh, what was it..." :)  ..  Add-On installed. "Good find" number 2! Also, the add-ons existence makes me wonder if there's "something broken" with the improved algo altogether. How does Chrome handle it? Dunno. But my hunch is Chrome users don't suffer "sudden history loss". I'd always advocated for FF - today is a bad day for my support of FF :(   ..   Again, cheers David!